# Lucene match only exact query ignoring repeated terms

Tags: regex, lucene

Given an index where the values of a property 'nodeName' reflect the list below, how can I use Lucene to return only nodes with an exactly matched name?

```
foo
bar
foobar
foo foo bar
```

If I search 'bar', I only want the second node returned.

I thought I could use regex in the search term (something like `"+nodeName:\"/^{0}$\"` where {0} is the query) to match on the start and end of the string, but that's not working - it returns all nodes that include the query.

Also tried an inclusive range `("+nodeName: [{0} TO {0}]")` which returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Regex query isn't really going to help you here.  The regex in your query can not span multiple analyzed terms.  The best way to ensure that a match spans the entire contents of a field is to index it in a way that facilitates that, that is, as a single token.  I'm assuming this is a `TextField` using `StandardAnalyzer`, or something like it.  In order to match against the whole input, a `StringField` would be a good choice, which would index the entire field as one token.  Then a simple `TermQuery` could be used for this sort of search:

- `TermQuery("nodeName","bar")` Would match only the document specified, rather than multiples
- `TermQuery("nodeName","foo foo bar")` Would also match the last example, rather than none at all.

If you also need to be able to perform more standard (full-text) searches against analyzed text in this field, I would recommend indexing the same content in two separate fields, one `StringField` and one `TextField`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I rethought my approach and ended up not using Lucene. Got the result I needed so all good.